# D3.JS: How to animate lines

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

Relatively new to D3, an have a question regarding the translation (animation) of lines.  I animate circles using the following code:

```
var data = d3.range(100).map(function() {
    return new agent(
        0,
        0,
        (Math.random()-0.5)*.05,
        (Math.random()-0.5)*.05,
        'rgb(255, 0, 213)');
});

var circles = canvas.selectAll('circle')
        .data(data)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr('cy', function(d) {
            return d.y;
        })
        .attr('r', 5)
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            return d.color;
        });

circles.attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
});
```

The last 3 lines in particular are of interest to me - is there an equivalent `translate` for lines?

Comment: There's a best practice for animating svg paths (D3 lines). Have a look here: http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  `transform=translate` simply moves the element (it doesn't not animate it).  A "d3 line" is usually a `path` element, can you apply a `transform` to it?  Yes you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible options to animate lines in D3, e.g.

**Changing the underlying data**

```
svg.select(".line")
    .duration(animationLength)
    .attr("d", valueline(lineData))
```

valueLine is a `d3.svg.line()` function.

**Filling the line from start to end via [`stroke-dashoffset`](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)**

```
var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", 200 + " " + 200)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 200)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .transition()
    .duration(animationLength)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

**Using `transform` to move the line**

```
svg.select(".line")
    .duration(animationLength)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 * Math.random() + "," + 100 * Math.random() + ")");
```

```js
var animationLength = 2000;
var lineData = [{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 5
}, {
    "x": 20,
    "y": 20
}, {
    "x": 40,
    "y": 10
}, {
    "x": 60,
    "y": 40
}, {
    "x": 80,
    "y": 5
}, {
    "x": 100,
    "y": 60
}];
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .interpolate("linear");

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
        return d.x * (Math.random() + 0.5);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return d.y * (Math.random() + 0.5);
    });

var svg = d3.select("#line")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);

var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", 200 + " " + 200)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 200)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .transition()
    .duration(animationLength)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

svg = d3.select("body").transition();

svg.select(".line")
    .delay(animationLength)
    .duration(animationLength)
    .attr("d", valueline(lineData))
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 * Math.random() + "," + 100 * Math.random() + ")");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="line"></div>
```